# Assigning variables and sending to database once all values assigned python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

This is my first python script.  I am trying to get data from an Arduino, read it on a Raspberry Pi and save it to the database.  The code works separately (I can assign the variable correctly and send the data to the database but can't seem to get them both to work. I'm not sure my logic works (setting variables to null and then saving once they all have values).  Thanks for the input.

```
    import re
    import serial
    import MySQLdb
    import time

db =MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost",user = "root",passwd = "example", db = "arduino")
ser =serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600) 

humidityPattern = "Humidity\:(\d\d\.\d\d)"
tempDhPattern = "TemperatureDH\:(\d\d\.\d\d)"
barometerPattern = "PressureBMP\:(\d\d\.\d\d)"
tempBmpPattern = "TemperatureBMP\:(\d\d\.\d\d)"
tempTmpPattern = "TemperatureTMP\:(\d\d\.\d\d)"
blLightPattern = "BLLight\:(\d+)"
brLightPattern = "BRLight\:(\d+)"
frLightPattern = "FRLight\:(\d+)"
flLightPattern = "FLLight\:(\d+)"


while 1:
    line = ser.readline()
    humidity = None
    tempDh = None
    pressure = None
    tempBmp = None
    tempTmp = None
    blLight = None
    brLight = None
    frLight = None
    flLight = None

    #Humidity Sensor
    m = re.match(humidityPattern, line)
    if m is not None:      
        humidity = m.group(1)
        print "Humidity is "+humidity

    m = re.match(tempDhPattern, line)
    if m is not None:
        tempDh= m.group(1)
        print "Humidity Temp is "+tempDh

    #Pressure Sensor
    m = re.match(barometerPattern, line)
    if m is not None:
        pressure = m.group(1)
        print "Pressure is "+tempDh

    m = re.match(tempBmpPattern, line)
    if m is not None:
        tempBmp= m.group(1)
        print "Pressure Temp is "+tempBmp

    #Temp Sensor
    m = re.match(tempTmpPattern, line)
    if m is not None:
        tempTmp= m.group(1)
        print "Temp is "+tempTmp

    #Light Sensors
    m = re.match(blLightPattern, line)
    if m is not None:
        blLight= m.group(1)
        print "BL Light is "+ blLight

    m = re.match(brLightPattern, line)
    if m is not None:
        brLight= m.group(1)
        print "BR Light is "+ brLight

    m = re.match(frLightPattern, line)
    if m is not None:
        frLight = m.group(1)
        print "FR Light is "+ frLight

    m = re.match(flLightPattern, line)
    if m is not None:
        flLight = m.group(1)
        print "FL Light is "+ flLight

    if humidity and tempDh and pressure and tempBmp and tempTmp and blLight and brLight and frLight and flLight is not None:
        with db:
            cur = db.cursor()
            cur.execute('insert into weather(humidity, temp_dh, pressure,temp_bmp, temp_tmp, bl_light, br_light, fr_light, fl_light) values("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")'%(humidity, tempDh, pressure, tempBmp, tempTmp, blLight, brLight, frLight, flLight ))
            time.sleep(5)
            print 'upload'
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is in the test:

```
if humidity and tempDh and pressure and tempBmp and tempTmp and blLight and brLight and frLight and flLight is not None:
```

which only tests for `None` the very last variable, `flLight`.  However if, as it seems, all the others are either `None` or a non-empty string, this **should** accidentally work because `None` is falsy and every non-empty string is truthy.

So a bigger problem is that every time through the loop you're throwing away every value you've previously read, whether you've saved them or not.

To fix **that**, add a boolean flag `must_init` and change the logic to something like, at the start of your loop:

must_init = True
while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    if must_init:
        humidity = None
        tempDh = None
        pressure = None
        tempBmp = None
        tempTmp = None
        blLight = None
        brLight = None
        frLight = None
        flLight = None
        must_init = False

and set `must_init = True` again only at the very end within the `with` statement right after the now-final `print 'upload'`.

This way, you will null out all variables only (A) the first time or (B) right after saving their previous values to the DB, which seems to be more correct logic.

Other simplifying improvements are possible (e.g keep the variables as items in a dict, so you don't have to enumerate them in the `any` check; have the RE expression also in a dict keyed by the same name you use in the variables dict to enormously compact and simplify your code) but the key point is that the code with the addition of the `must_init` boolean flag as I suggest before should **work** -- you can improve it after!-)